# jQuery slideToggle and Background-Color

Tags: jquery, css, slidetoggle

I've whipped up a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vko9fv7s/14/) which simulates the Problem or use the snippet below. As you can see when you press the Arrow button the Background-colour squeezes back into it's original shape. It Looses the padding/margin values.

Is there a way to supress or work around this behaviour?

EDIT: Just to clarify, this is a PART of the HTML created output.
I Added a border to the DIV. As you can see the background leaves the div-border in the open state. When the toggle triggers the background color which was placed outside the border is removed.

```js
$(".togglebutton").click(function(event) {
  $(event.target).toggleClass("down up")
  $(this).parent().next(".list").slideToggle(500)
});
```

```css
.background2nd {
  background: rgb(254, 254, 254);
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(254, 254, 254, 1) 0%, rgba(254, 254, 254, 1) 0%, rgba(219, 219, 219, 1) 39%, rgba(209, 209, 209, 1) 100%, rgba(226, 226, 226, 1) 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(254, 254, 254, 1)), color-stop(0%, rgba(254, 254, 254, 1)), color-stop(39%, rgba(219, 219, 219, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(209, 209, 209, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(226, 226, 226, 1)));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(254, 254, 254, 1) 0%, rgba(254, 254, 254, 1) 0%, rgba(219, 219, 219, 1) 39%, rgba(209, 209, 209, 1) 100%, rgba(226, 226, 226, 1) 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(254, 254, 254, 1) 0%, rgba(254, 254, 254, 1) 0%, rgba(219, 219, 219, 1) 39%, rgba(209, 209, 209, 1) 100%, rgba(226, 226, 226, 1) 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(254, 254, 254, 1) 0%, rgba(254, 254, 254, 1) 0%, rgba(219, 219, 219, 1) 39%, rgba(209, 209, 209, 1) 100%, rgba(226, 226, 226, 1) 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(254, 254, 254, 1) 0%, rgba(254, 254, 254, 1) 0%, rgba(219, 219, 219, 1) 39%, rgba(209, 209, 209, 1) 100%, rgba(226, 226, 226, 1) 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fefefe', endColorstr='#e2e2e2', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
}
.background1st {
  background: rgb(248, 255, 232);
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(248, 255, 232, 1) 0%, rgba(227, 245, 171, 1) 33%, rgba(183, 223, 45, 1) 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(248, 255, 232, 1)), color-stop(33%, rgba(227, 245, 171, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(183, 223, 45, 1)));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(248, 255, 232, 1) 0%, rgba(227, 245, 171, 1) 33%, rgba(183, 223, 45, 1) 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(248, 255, 232, 1) 0%, rgba(227, 245, 171, 1) 33%, rgba(183, 223, 45, 1) 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(248, 255, 232, 1) 0%, rgba(227, 245, 171, 1) 33%, rgba(183, 223, 45, 1) 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(248, 255, 232, 1) 0%, rgba(227, 245, 171, 1) 33%, rgba(183, 223, 45, 1) 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f8ffe8', endColorstr='#b7df2d', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
}
.backgroundlist {
  margin-left: -15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.arrow {
  border: 5px solid #444;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.arrow.down {
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
}
.arrow.up {
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  position: relative;
  top: -7px;
}
.arrow.left {
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
}
.arrow.right {
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Meine Events&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="arrow down togglebutton"></span></h2>
<div class="list" style="  border: 1px solid;">
  <p class="background2nd backgroundlist">Test</p>
  <p class="background1st backgroundlist">Test</p>
  <p class="background2nd backgroundlist">Test</p>
  <p class="background1st backgroundlist">Test</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You are missing `event` in `$(".togglebutton").click(function(event) {`

try with this:

```
$(".togglebutton").click(function(event) {
  $(event.target).toggleClass("down")
  $(event.target).toggleClass("up")
  $(this).parent().next(".list").slideToggle(500)
});
```

You are missing close tag for `<a href="/yii/backend/web/index.php/site/event?id=29">` too

Comment: true, but not related as it seems

Comment: Jerry's answer seems correct. What else you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Maverick forget the tags, not related. i made a simpler html code https://jsfiddle.net/vko9fv7s/14/ the code IS working, just not "right"